# What are the applications of Pancake Sorting?

Tags: algorithm

I recently found out about this Pancake Sorting: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pancake-sorting/ and I was wondering why do we use it when we have far better sorting algorithms than this, does its application prove to be really beneficial in some certain kind of scenarios ?

Comment: When you're sorting your pancakes with a spatula.

Comment: Does there have to be a reason for it? It looks more like sort of a fun-algorithm. Also might be more of a theoretical problem, like how many moves are required to solve a rubiks cube.

Comment: @tobias_k Of-course not. There doesn't have to be a reason. I was just wondering if there was.

Answer (score 1):

Though I have no practical experience with this sorting algorithm, I found these lines useful in wikipedia:

> ..It is a variation of the sorting problem in which the only allowed
>   operation is to reverse the elements of some prefix of the sequence.
>   Unlike a traditional sorting algorithm, which attempts to sort with
>   the fewest comparisons possible, the goal is to sort the sequence in
>   as few reversals as possible.

It also states that, it has applications in parallel processor networks, in which it can provide an effective routing algorithm between processors. I, personally also faced several online judge programming contest problems that require *minimum number of reversals to sort a sequence*. Although programming contest problem are not real world problem example.